# Why does Java and C# place the main function inside of a class?

Tags: java, c#, oop

I don't understand what is the point of placing the `main` function inside of a class! Is it so they can say that Java and C# are fully object oriented?

Comment: In both languages, *all* methods are part of a type. There's nothing special about `main`.

Comment: I think you have this the wrong way round. It's because they are OO languages that the `main` function is in a class.

Comment: It should be noted that .NET can have classless assemblies - you can have an entry point that resides in the global module. They are, however, basically stand-alone because they cannot be used from say, C# which expects them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do this for reasons of simplicity.  If the main function was to be allowed to be outside of a class, then the language would have to support an entire new mechanism for declaring functions outside of classes.  No such mechanism currently exists, and frankly, it would be completely unnecessary.  By not adding unnecessary stuff to the language, they keep the language simple.

Answer (score 3):

`static` methods are not OOP so this would have little point.

Java requires that all code are inside a class i.e. inside a class file.  If you don't do this you would have to put it somewhere and you wouldn't gain much by doing making an exception for `main`.  Better to keep things simple.

> I don't understand what is the point of placing the main function inside of a class!

Instead of asking "Why not do something" it can be better to ask "Why do something" and if there isn't a very good reason, often it is better not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer behind *main* inside the class lays in Processes and Threads topic.

Read [Oracle's Processes and Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html) to understand the topic better.

The idea is that your class requires a thread to run at. You class is part of your application. Each application requires a Process and at least one Thread to run at. By default, the *main* thread is used, this means that all your class' code runs inside *main* thread by default.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. This isn't about threads .. its about entrypoints.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that defining *main* inside class explicitly tells the class to run its code inside *main* thread.

Comment: It certainly doesn't have to - that is an implementation detail. .NET certainly doesn't require that an entry point be inside of an object. C# as a language enforces it - the CLR as a runtime doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

These both languages were created with the object orientation in mind without any backward compatibility baggage (unlike c++ for example which is also considered to be object oriented, but it's backward  compatibility with c enforces it to allow the concept of free methods, methods defined outside of any class), and it's name implies all it's building block are based on an object.